# How can I import CSV data with newline characters in its values into a GCloud Big Query table?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bq

My `bq load` command and error

```
$ bq load --replace --source_format=CSV --autodetect temp.BQTable ./source.csv
Upload complete.
Waiting on bqjob_123 ... (0s) Current status: DONE
BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job 'my-project-id-123:bqjob_123': Error
while reading data, error message: Error detected while parsing row starting at position: 333. Error: Missing close
double quote (") character.
Failure details:
- Error while reading data, error message: CSV processing encountered
too many errors, giving up. Rows: 0; errors: 1; max bad: 0; error
percent: 0
```

Excel and my node.js module for Csv serialization can process data with values with newlines just fine.

Papaparse, my npm module for serializing, uses `'\r\n'` as the default newline to separate rows so there shouldn't be any ambiguity there.

Here's some sample csv data, ie, source.csv

```
id,name
1,"this value
includes a newline"
```

bq and Cloud SDK versions

```
$ gcloud components update


Your current Cloud SDK version is: 289.0.0
You will be upgraded to version: 337.0.0

┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                      These components will be updated.                      │
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬────────────┬──────────┤
│                         Name                        │  Version   │   Size   │
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼────────────┼──────────┤
│ BigQuery Command Line Tool                          │     2.0.67 │  < 1 MiB │
│ BigQuery Command Line Tool (Platform Specific)      │     2.0.65 │  < 1 MiB │
│ Cloud SDK Core Libraries                            │ 2021.04.16 │ 18.0 MiB │
│ Cloud SDK Core Libraries (Platform Specific)        │ 2021.03.12 │  < 1 MiB │
│ Cloud Storage Command Line Tool                     │       4.61 │  3.9 MiB │
│ Cloud Storage Command Line Tool (Platform Specific) │       4.59 │  < 1 MiB │
│ gcloud cli dependencies                             │ 2021.04.16 │ 10.8 MiB │
│ gcloud cli dependencies                             │ 2021.04.16 │  < 1 MiB │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴────────────┴──────────┘
```

I was on version 289 because they patched newer version to not allow you to import a file (CSV, JSON, etc) of size 100 MB or bigger into BQ using `bq load` :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the flag below to your command:

```
--allow_quoted_newlines=true
```

Not sure if this will work with `\r\n`, it definetly work for me for `\n` encoded newlines.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all newline and carriage return characters from all string values in csv.

Javascript

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const rows = [{ id: 1, name: `this value
  includes a newline` 
}];

rows.forEach(row => {
  return _.mapValues(row, value => typeof value === 'string'
    ? value.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, ' ')
    : value
  );
});
```

This isn't a good solution since it discards data and assumes those newlines weren't important. Let's hope there aren't newlines in your PK's or foreign fields.